# How do I configure Xen GPU passthrough for my AMD Radeon GPU?

Tags: graphics, xen

I have an Ubuntu Server 12.10 setup with Xen 4.2.0 installed (compiled from source) and an AMD Radeon 7750 GPU. My Xen installation appears to be working and I can create virtual machines for example.

I have set up a virtual machine and it appears to be working fine when connecting to it with VNC. However, after changing the config to enable GPU passthrough, nothing is appearing on my monitor and VNC just displays "serial0" and does not allow me to do anything.

In order to enable GPU passthrough I appended the following to my config file:

```
gfx_passthru=1
pci=['01:00.0']
```

How can I pass my GPU to my virtual machine properly?

Comment: Where did you find that `gfx_passthru`?

Comment: @Nils http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_VGA_Passthrough#Using_Xen_VGA_graphics_passthru

Comment: Which VNC client are you using, on which platform? Have you hidden the AMD card from Dom0? If so, how? Please provide `sudo lspci` on both the host and the guest (remove the gfx_passthru to get it to boot, but leave the PCI passed through). Do you want the graphics card passed through as the secondary adapter (second screen) or the primary with no VNC adapter? Xen VNC can't and won't show what's on the passed through graphics adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with a 7750 using secondary passthrough and a Win7 guest. To do so, set gfx_passthru = 0, start your domain and open a VNC console to the domain. Install the Catalyst drivers. Reboot. You'll still view the BIOS and OS boot process via VNC at this point, but once the OS loads the Catalyst drivers, you should see the login screen coming up on your monitor.

I haven't had any luck with primary passthrough yet and nor tried a Linux guest with any kind of passthrough. If I do find anything on either of these, I'll provide a further update.

Comment: Do you know if the catalyst drivers are required or can you use the open source radeon drivers also? I only had luck with the catalyst driver.

Answer (score 0):

[This list](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenVGAPassthroughTestedAdapters#ATI.2FAMD_display_adapters) might be outdated - but it does not show the 7750 as "working".

Apart from that I would try to really pass it to the DomU - by hiding it from the Dom0. But for that you propably need a second card for the Dom0 (or live with a serial console).